# cache or temporary memory in plotly dash

Tags: flask, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a dashboard using plotly dash. I have set debug mode to True. 
Every time I make a change, pandas read my excel file all from the beginning, this itself consumes around 10 to 15 mins.

Is there anyway , where my df can be store in cache or temp memory , so that , while debugging or making any changes, reading the file part is skipped an can be read from he cache ?

Basically any method that will help me speed up the process in plotly dash.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I'd suggest using a much smaller version of your dataset for the debugging stage of this project.

Also, pandas shouldn't be taking 15 minutes... What is the format of your file?

Comment: I am using .xlsx format excel file. The size of the file is approx 55MB.

Comment: Consider converting your xls file to something more serializable – such as csv or json. Do that upfront --> then load that csv or json.

Comment: 55MB is really small. This shouldn't take more than a second or two...

Comment: My xls has multiple sheets, so while converting to csv, will each sheet get converted to a single csv file ? and later shld I concat and read all the csv files in one go using pandas ?

Comment: Perhaps. If the sheet name / order matters – then perhaps create a new field "sheet ID" for your new df's. And yes, concatenating them upfront would def be worth your while.